# Missing $ error when no math is being used

Tags: compiling

This line

```
The variable names are HTTP_PROXY with the value http://myproxy:80
```

causes

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.91 The variable names are HTTP_PROXY with the value http://myproxy:80
?
```

Removing this line solves the problem but I want this line in the document.

Comment: Educated guess: HTTP_PROXY, i.e. the underscore which is only allowed in math mode or use `HTTP\_PROXY` or verbatim output, like `\verb!HTTP_PROXY!`

Comment: Isn't there an error that shows a linebreak at the `_` before that?

Comment: no but you have misquoted it the error surely has a linebreak at `_` doesn't it (look in the log if you are looking at some editor-filtered view)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand now. In the log, it shows a line break.

Comment: Your editor is not helping if it hides that, the linebreak is designed to show the exact point of the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_` is reserved for mathmode (usually), indicating a subscript content to follow.

Either use a verbatim approach, or `\_` for explicit underscore characters. Using `\url` for this does also work.

Some options, e.g. with `url` package as well

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{url}



\begin{document}

The variable names are \verb!HTTP_PROXY! with the value \url{http://myproxy:80}

The variable names are HTTP\_PROXY with the value \url{http://myproxy:80}

The variable names are \url{HTTP_PROXY} with the value \url{http://myproxy:80}

\end{document}
```